# Is there a variational interpretation for the equation $\operatorname{div}(\star \circ \bigwedge^k df\circ \star )=0$?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, soft-question, calculus-of-variations, jacobians

$\newcommand{\id}{\operatorname{Id}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\TM}{\operatorname{TM}}
\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}
\newcommand{\Cof}{\operatorname{Cof}}
\newcommand{\Det}{\operatorname{Det}}
\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal{N}}
\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}
\newcommand{\TM}{\operatorname{T\M}}
\newcommand{\TN}{\operatorname{T\N}}
\newcommand{\TstarM}{T^*\M}$Let $\M$, $\N$ be $d$-dimensional oriented Riemannian manifolds. For a smooth map $f:\M \to \N$, we define its *$k$-cofactor map* as

$$\Cof^k df :=  \star_{f^*\TN}^{d-k}\circ \bigwedge^{d-k} df\circ\star_{\TM}^k \in  \Omega^k\big(\M,\Lambda_k(f^*\TN)\big),
$$
where the $\star$'s denote the relevant Hodge dual operators.

---

One can show that **for every** $f\in C^\infty(\M,\N)$,
$$
\delta_{\nabla^{\Lambda_k(f^*T\N)}} \Cof^k df = 0, \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
where $\delta_{\nabla^{\Lambda_k(f^*T\N)}}$ is the covariant coderivative
$$
\delta_{\nabla^{\Lambda_k(f^*T\N)}}: \Omega^k\big(\M;\Lambda_k(f^*\TN)\big) \to  \Omega^{k-1}\big(\M;\Lambda_k(f^*\TN)\big).
$$
Here $\nabla^{\Lambda_k(f^*T\N)}$ is the natural connection induced on the exterior power $\Lambda_k(f^*T\N)$, from the pullback connection of the Levi–Civita connection on $T\N$.

---

> **Question:** Is there any variational interpretation or derivation for equation \eqref{1} above?

For $k=1$,
$$\Cof df:=\Cof^1 df=  \star_{f^*\TN}^{d-1}\circ \bigwedge^{d-1} df\circ\star_{\TM}^1 \in  \Omega^1\big(\M,f^*\TN\big),
$$
is the standard *cofactor map* of $df$ (defined in Riemannian context). In that case there is a clear, classical, well-known  variational interpretation:

$\delta (\Cof df)=0$ is the Euler–Lagrange equation of the Jacobian functional $$E(f)=\int_{\M} \Det df\, \operatorname{Vol}_{\M}=\int_{\M} f^* \operatorname{Vol}_{\N},$$ which is a null-Lagrangian. (This can be shown directly: integrals of pullbacks of closed forms by homotopic maps are equal; this is essentially Stokes's theorem.)

---

**The question is whether there is a variational interpretation for $k>1$.**

I am aware of the fact that in Euclidean context, minors of arbitrary degree are null-Lagrangians, but it's not clear how to define such "minors" invariantly/intrinsically for mappings between Riemannian manifolds.

**Actually, I am not sure whether and how equation \eqref{1} reduces or connects to the Euler–Lagrange equations of the minors even in the Euclidean case:**

Since $$\delta_{\nabla^{\Lambda_k(f^*T\N)}} \Cof^k df \in\Omega^{k-1}\big(\M;\Lambda_k(f^*\TN)\big),$$ equation \eqref{1} is locally a system of ${d \choose k-1}{d \choose k}$ scalar equations.

Let $f:\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$, and let $I,J$ be multi-indices of length $r$.

The Euler-Lagrange equation of $E(f)=\int_{\Omega} [df]^I_J$ (we integrate the determinant of the $(I,J)$-minor of $f$), in fact consists of $r$ scalar equations. (only $r$ components of the variation field play any real role).

**Thus, the number of scalar equations in the E-L equations of all the minors of degree $r$ is ${d \choose r}^2r$.** Furthermore, the E-L equation of a minor of degree $r$, is essentially a derivation of $r-1$ minors of $df$.

Since $\delta_{\nabla^{\Lambda_k(f^*T\N)}} \Cof^k df $ is a derivation of $d-k$ minors of $df$ (recall that $\Cof^k df \simeq \bigwedge^{d-k} df$), the only way it could correspond (in the Euclidean case) to E-L equations of minors of degree $r$ is if $r-1=d-k$.

Then for the number of scalar equations in the E-L equations to coincide with the number of scalar equations in equation \eqref{1}, we must have  $${d \choose r}^2r={d \choose k-1}{d \choose k}, \,\,\, \text{ where } \,\,\, r-1=d-k.$$

It can be easily checked that this happens if and only if $k=1$, which is the well-known Jacobian case mentioned above.

In fact, for $1<k$, the number of scalar equations of the minors's E-L, is strictly greater than the number of scalar equations in the system $\eqref{1}$. Thus, when $k>1$, there are "more" E-L equations associated with the $d-k+1$ minors, than equations in $\eqref{1}$.

**Still, perhaps some "direct" connection is possible.** In particular, can we show that the E-L equations imply the given equation $\eqref{1}$, in a straightforward manner? (This seems the reasonable direction of the implication, since the E-L equations have more scalar equations than equation $\eqref{1}$).

I stress again, that all these equations, both the minors's E-L equations, and $\eqref{1}$, are 'trivial' in the sense that they are satisfied by all maps. The question is whether one can see a direct connection between these two "tautological" systems of equations.

Comment: Unlike TeX, MathJax preserves unwanted whitespace, so, for example $\newcommand\a{a}$ $\newcommand\b{b}$ $\a\b$ `$\newcommand\a{a}$ $\newcommand\b{b}$ $\a\b$` has two unwanted spaces. Similarly, line breaks outside of math mode are preserved as literal line breaks in the text. This produced a large blank space at the beginning of your post, so I edited the source to remove it. (While I was there, I also used `\label{1}`/`\eqref{1}` instead of literally reproducing the equation number.) Also, TeX note: `\DeclareMathOperator\a{a}` is a shorter form of `\newcommand\a{\operatorname{a}}`.

Comment: Thank you very much for improving the presentation, and for your comments. I definitely learned several new things from your comment, and from your edit. I will try to keep these lessons in mind for future questions.